# Error “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined” en datatables.net cuando se ajusta a una pantalla chica (responsive)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have my functional datatables when it is in high resolution, but when it is on a small screen it does not capture data from the server.

Large screen: 
[image]

Small Screen: [image]

As if not recognize each row correctly.
Here's the way I created the table with datatables:

```html
var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    filter: false,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'tabla/usuarios',
        global: false,
        method: 'POST',
        data: function (d) {
            d.campo = $('input[name=filter_campo]').val();
            d.perfil = $('select[name=filter_perfil]').val();
            d.estados = $('select[name=filter_estados]').val();
        }
    },
    columns: [
            {data: 0, searchable: false, orderable: false, render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
                return meta.row+1;
            }
        },
        {data: 1},
        {data: 2},
        {data: 10},
        {data: 11},
        {data: 5, 
            render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
                        if (data) {
                            return '<input id="toggle" data-info="toggle'+full.id+'" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Activo" data-off="Inactivo" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">';
                        }else {
                            return '<input id="toggle" data-info="toggle'+full.id+'" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Activo" data-off="Inactivo" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">';
                        }
            }
        },
        {data: 9, searchable: false, orderable: false},
    ],
    search: {
        "regex": true
    },
    order: [[1, 'asc']],
    fnDrawCallback: function() {
        $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapToggle();
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            placement : 'top',
            html : true
        }); 
    }
});

editar("#table tbody",table);
```

How do I get the data from the table when I click on one of the buttons, example "Editar" (Edit in spanish)

```html
var editar = function(tbody, table){
    $(tbody).on("click","button.editar", function(){
        var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        $('#editar_id').val(data[0]);
        $('#editar_alias').val(data[1]);
        $('#editar_correo').val(data[2]);
        $('#editar_perfil').val(data[8]);
        $('#ModalEditar').modal('show');
        $("#editar-alias").first().focus();
    })
}
```

Note: in the responsive the property loses the button "switch".

I'm from venezuela, excuse my little English.

**UPDATE 1**
No responsive:
[image]

Responsive:
[image]

**UPDATE 2**
Not responsive:
[image]

Responsive:
[image]

Comment: Usted sabe que hay [es.so]. Necesitamos más detalles sobre lo que quieres... and that's as much Spanish as I can do at one time :). Basically, we need to know: what you were expecting to happen that didn't happen, what you've tried, error messages (as text, not in an picture), etc.. Lo siento, pero esas son las reglas.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan What I expect you to do is show the "modal" by clicking the buttons as the first image does. The first image (in large screen) shows the modal, in the second it sends an error saying that it is not "data" and therefore does not show the "modal".

Comment: In "es.stackoverflow.com" there are not many who master that plugin.

Comment: You need to debug the `editar` function to see what's happening.  I'm guessing that in responsive mode, `table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data()` is failing

Comment: What I understand how the plugin works: when the table is complete (not responsive) the data is stored in each row and is captured with "var data = table.row ($ (this) .parents (" tr ")). data();" Obtaining the value of the row in which is the button to which it clicked. What happens when you are on a small screen (responsive)? Create another row which is not the one with the data.

Comment: @markpsmith Edit the question and specify what happens.

Comment: SO debug and see what is different.... Is it rendered as multiple rows instead of one?

Comment: @epascarello When it is responsive it creates other rows, thus adapting itself to the resolution of the screen. But does not capture the data in that row.

Comment: So is the data attached to one of the new parents? Are you looking at the right place for the data attribute?

Comment: @epascarello Wait, I already changed the question in a moment.

Comment: @epascarello Already edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the datatables plugin when it becomes responsive another row is created, as we can see here:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

To capture the data we have to differentiate if the button is in a child column, as follows:

```html
var editar = function(tbody, table){
    $(tbody).on("click","button.editar", function(){
        if(table.row(this).child.isShown()){
            var data = table.row(this).data();
        }else{
            var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        }
        $('#editar_id').val(data[0]);
        $('#editar_alias').val(data[1]);
        $('#editar_correo').val(data[2]);
        $('#editar_perfil').val(data[8]);
        $('#editar_ver_perfil').val(data[4]);
        $('#ModalEditar').modal('show');
        $("#editar-nombres").first().focus();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are going to have to check to see where the button is located and than select the parent row with the inputs.

```
$(tbody).on("click","button.editar", function(){
    var button = $(this),  //button that was clicked
        row = button.closest("tr");  //table row parent is in

    //check to see if we are in a child row, 
    // if we are, select the previous one
    if (row.is(".child")) {  //if we are 
        row = row.prev("tr");
    }

    console.log(row);

});
```

Comment: Guide me of your questions and look at the children API, this guided me: https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html. Thx bro.

Comment: Check my solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624582/error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined-en-datatables/41644173#41644173

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you refresh.

Try with  `$('#dt').DataTable().ajax.reload();`